# npm install does not download one specific file

Tags: yo, npmjs

I have created one `yo generator` and I can see the code is available in github and also showing in `yo generator` list.

Its working perfectly when I do `npm install` to download the generator code into my local machine and also when scaffold application using yo command.

Only problem is one of my file (systemjs.config.js) which is in the /generator/template folder is not getting downloaded niter from `npm install` nor when I scaffold application using `yo` command.

generator link [git link to generator](https://github.com/aniruddhadas9/generator-angular2-with-router)

command to download and scaffold from `yo generator`

```
npm install -g yo
npm install -g generator-angular2-with-router
yo angular2-with-router
```

Comment: one difference I found is the .gitignore file skips all js file as its a typescript project. that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occurring due to `.gitingore` file which was ignoring all the .js files as the project is in typescript. I was ignoring all my .js and .js.map files in my git ignore file

as `systemjs.config.js` file is a js file, its has been ignored by publish or something was happening with npm and it was not downloading.

Now I changed my .gitignore file and  so that specific `.js and .js.map` file will be ignored and it resolved my problem.